# How to call the overriden function in the singleton

Tags: c++, singleton

I am new to C++ and recently I have a problem of calling an overriden function from a singleton, the example code is:

```
class ParentClass
{
public:
ParentClass(){};
~ParentClass(){};

private:

    static ParentClass * mInstance;

    virtual methodA()
    {
       //...
    }

};

ParentClass * ParentClass::mInstance = new ParentClass;

class ChildClass : public ParentClass
{
private:

    virtual methodA() override
    {
      //....
    };
}
```

Is there anyway to call the overriden methodA for the mInstance?

Comment: ParentClass * ParentClass::mInstance = new ChildClass;

Comment: Try Scott Meyer's singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Change from `ParentClass * ParentClass::mInstance = new ParentClass;` to `ParentClass * ParentClass::mInstance = new ChildClass;` You need to instantiate the child class that overrides the function.

Otherwise, no, with the given `mInstance` (as instance of `ParentClass`)  there is no way of calling the overriden function

Answer (score 0):

Make this following change:

```
ParentClass * ParentClass::mInstance = new ChildClass;
```

Otherwise you will not be able to call overriden methodA.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't polymorphically call an overriden function that is marked **private** in the base class. A private function can only be called by the owning class itself. If you want a class' function to be exclusively visible to its derived children, then mark it as **protected**.

And your class `ParentClass` is not a singleton. A singleton class can't have a public constructor as there must only be *one* static instance. Ever.

It would also seem meaningless to inherit from a singleton class as the derived class, like its base, can never be constructed during runtime (unless the base's ctor is *protected*, but then it is starting to smell). All it can do is to access static members of the base or itself.

Anyway, the idiomatic C++-singleton class looks like this:

```
class singleton {
public:
    singleton(const singleton&) = delete;
    singleton& operator=(const singleton&) = delete;
    static singleton& get_instance() {
        static singleton instance;
        return instance;
    }
private:
    singleton() {}
};
```